# Mount Linux USB Burner on Windows

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, dvd, burner

Is it possible to mount a DVD burner located on a Ubuntu Linux box as a regular DVD Burner device on Windows?

I have a task to rdp into a remote Windows box from Linux (which I have solved via rdesktop), but also need to use the local USB DVD Burner on the remote Windows system.

I read the fine manpage for rdesktop and could only find the -r  option, but does not specifically mention optical media.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated !!!

Comment: Something like this should work http://superuser.com/a/316750.

Comment: That would work, but I'd like to share the raw /dev/sr0 to the remote windows box - in such a way that windows sees it as a real device.